# Rewrite part of URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite part of a URL with a 301 htaccess rewrite.
So far I got this

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?option=com_payplans&view=subscription&task=display&subscription_key=(.*)$ /subscriptiondetails/display/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

I want to go from

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_payplans&view=subscription&task=display&subscription_key=8O56WXCMQEZ5
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/subscriptiondetails/display/8O56WXCMQEZ5
```

Just can't quite figure out what I'm missing or doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `RewriteCond` to match query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_payplans&view=subscription&task=display&subscription_key=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /subscriptiondetails/display/%1? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: THANK YOU! :-) Works like a charm!